# Which repo should I use to resolve com.facebook:react-android issues

Tags: android, reactjs, build.gradle, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on a mobile app when I sync gradle it always fails with 3 errors

Failed to resolve: com.facebook.react:react-native:0.72
Affected modules : ....

I have used as many repos that I know Google maven jitpack etc still no solution
Help I need a suggestion on a working repo and a classpath or implementation for this